# Pass Foreign Key via Post Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am doing an exercise of creating an helpdesk system. I'm using code first so i create some scripts that i'll describe briefly.

This class is my main class

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Descrição")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public TicketStatus TicketStatus { get; set; }
    public byte TicketStatusId { get; set; }
}
```

and i created this class to handle ticket answer with an fk to a ticket

```
public class TicketAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

To create my form i created a viewmodel to handle all ticket answers

```
public class AnswerTicketViewModel
{
    //public IEnumerable<TicketStatus> TicketStatus { get; set; }
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public List<TicketAnswer> TicketAnswer { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

and passing this form

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SaveAnswer", "Ticket"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Ticket.Id)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, 10, 50, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", disabled = "disabled", @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar Resposta" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

this is the action

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult SaveAnswer(TicketAnswer ticket)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var ticketStatus = _context.TicketStatus.ToList();
            var ticketAnswer = _context.TicketAnswer.Where(t => t.TicketId == ticket.Ticket.Id).ToList();

            var viewModel = new AnswerTicketViewModel
            {
                Ticket = ticket.Ticket,
                TicketAnswer = ticketAnswer
            };
            return View("AnswerTicketForm", viewModel);
        }

        _context.TicketAnswer.Add(ticket);
        _context.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Ticket");
    }
```

I'm getting an error "The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo_TicketAnswers_dbo_Tickets_TicketId" how i change that and handle this fk? I try all kinds of solution can someone give a tip?

Comment: The only value that your form posts back is for `Ticket.Id`. The only other form controls is for `Message` but that wont post a value because its dsabled. And the model in your view is `AnswerTicketViewModel` but the model in you POST method is `TicketAnswer` and `TicketAnswer` does not have a property named `TicketId` so nothing will be bound.

Comment: Nothing in you code is making much sense. View models for editing should not contain data models (just include a propery `int TicketId`, not `Ticket`) and why does it have a property `List<TicketAnswer>` when you never use it?

Comment: I use when but not when i save the form, i use it to make the view with all the answers

Comment: Remember, view model is a POCO specific for the view. You need only properties absolutely needed by the view.

Comment: Yeah i needed all of them, because i use some to render the view and some to use on the post method

Answer (score 0):

Got it guys on my viewmodel i put a variable that i set on the form to the id of the ticket and it persists on the post method

```
public class AnswerTicketViewModel
{
    //public IEnumerable<TicketStatus> TicketStatus { get; set; }
    public Ticket Ticket { get; set; }
    public int TicketId { get; set; }
    public List<TicketAnswer> OtherAnswers { get; set; }
    public TicketAnswer TicketAnswer { get; set; }
}

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.TicketId, new { Value=Model.Ticket.Id })
```

So i was able to handle the database with that foreign key, thanks guys